is there is a way to check server cpu and memory usage after doing performance test using karate framework
I have created performance test with Karate framework using Java and able to get the report with the detailed report of API call response time. But I would like to capture the server CPU and memory usage of the server. is there a way to get that detail after the karate test is done.

This is more a Gatling question, and based on this post I think the recommendation is that you have to run a separate monitoring tool e.g. Prometheus and then aggregate the reports somehow or use the Gatling commercial version. Hope someone else here has better ideas.

Prometheus and Grafana are good for monitoring. If it is on cloud then cloud provider also provides CPU and Memory usage data. Nagios is another widely used tool
